# How to access the Microsoft Distributed File System (DFS) hosted on an EC2 from AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, microsoft-distributed-file-system

Actually, I've Microsoft Distributed File System (DFS) hosted on an EC2, so I want to read all the files from a specific path in DFS. And this thing I want to achieve through lambda function.

I do have the following information:

file_path: `\\<DNS>\football\`

service_account: `username: ABC`
`secret: 123`

**Permission:** My lambda function has all the necessary permission to read the DFS

So, how do I retrieve all the file names located at that location using the lambda function?

Comment: How would you do it _outside_ of an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, this was basically accessed through the windows os

Comment: Then how would you access it without a Windows operating system? Are there calls available in .Net that can access/mount a DFS without using Windows?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that is what I'm looking for. it would be great to have any option in python based lambda function which I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of huddling and juggling, I could able to figure out the way to access any Windows file server like `FSx` and `DFS` using the lambda function(python) alone using `subprotocol`.

**Note**: Lambda function should have all the level access to file server read/write operation along with file server allowing to use the SMB Protocol by its client in any operation.

For more detail please follow this article which is insightful.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/enabling-smb-access-for-serverless-workloads/

**Desclamair**: There is no direct way to move the file directly from the s3 bucket to the file server using only the lambda function. We can use the other AWS services to make this movement directly from s3 to fileserver which is out of this context. Also if we can manage to mount the fileserver in the lambda function itself that we can do I guess.

**Procedure followed to copy the file from s3 to fileserver using lambda function alone.**

1. **Copy** the file from the **s3 bucket** to the lambda **temporary location**. i.e. `tmp/`
2. Perform the normal `read/write` file operation.

=> Open the file from the `tmp/` location in `read mode` **f1**

=> Open the same file in the remote file server using `smbclient` module present in `smbprotocal` library. **f2**

=> Write the content of the read by **f1** in file open by **f2** using the same `smbclient`